# Upgrading Ubuntu Mate 16.04 to 18.04(Dual Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, upgrade, ubuntu-mate

I'm planning on upgrading my ubuntu mate from 16.04 to 18.04, I have a dual boot setup with windows 10 and I'm using the grub boot manager. I had a couple of questions: 
a) is there a chance that the upgrade might break my dual boot setup?

b) will the upgrade affect any drivers(My NVidia GPU driver to be specific which I have set up for Cuda and cuDNN) or software (like Pycharm, VS code that I have installed?

c) will it affect any of my pip managers, libraries and python installations?
Any suggestions on how to upgrade, safety measures, additional steps, and recommendations are most welcome(for the record I'm following this guide https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-bionic-final-release/)

Comment: It sounds like you've added unofficial or 3rd party software to your system, as such the chance of breakage is a yes. QA-testing of release-upgrades is done using only Ubuntu repository software (I'm speaking generally, I've not done QA-test upgrades for Ubuntu-MATE), so if you want a flawless upgrade - remove all unofficial/3rd party sources & software, perform the release-upgrade, then add-back what you need. Your official Ubuntu-MATE is the guide I'd recommend too. *this is general comment only*

Comment: can you please elaborate more on 3rd party software(like does it include drivers and programming libraries) and will their presence affect grub as well while upgrading?

Comment: PPA's or personal-package-archives are an example of 3rd party sources for software (though software from the Ubuntu-MATE team in your case I'd treat as official even though it isn't, ie. https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).  Software from 'main', 'universe', 'restricted' & 'multiverse' are official (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) but other non-Canonical/non-Ubuntu sources are 3rd party.  They may use non-Ubuntu versioning for packages that cause there to have be seen as later for your initial release; but may stop release-upgrade..)

Comment: No I would not expect 3rd party software/sources to impact your grub; the problem is that apt/dpkg/.. tools use version numbers to upgrade; and there are many standards; 3rd parties are free to use non-Ubuntu standards.  (the various versioning-schemes only become an issue at release-upgrade time)

Comment: You could clone your machine, or rebuild another box/vm with like software [to your system] and use that to test to release-upgrade to see what issues you'll likely have.  If it's a pain to fix, my backup-fix is re-install using *something-else* which takes note of your added packages, erases system directories & installs, then re-adds back the software you added to your system (if available in sources).  I'm mentioning this as it's my fall-back, other people will have other methods.